# Cross join error with unnest array and user supplied data

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, select, unnest

I am trying to create a cross join in postgres

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[1,2])) AS t1(product_id)
CROSS JOIN
SELECT * FROM (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[5])) AS t2(category_id);
```

This gives error. I can not figure the problem.

Comment: Subqueries in the `FROM` clause need a table alias.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Can you please correct and post solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has unnecessary levels of nesting, which finally cause problem since some of the derived tables (ie subqueries) are not aliases.

You could just phrase this as:

```
select t1.product_id, t2.category_id
from unnest(array[1,2]) as t1(product_id)
cross join unnest(array[5]) AS t2(category_id);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This works as well

```
select * from 
    unnest(array[1,2]) t1(product_id), 
    unnest(array[5]) t2(category_id);
```